# End the execution of a script after a certain amount of time - Python

Tags: python, loops, time, pcap

Good evening everyone. Guys I'm implementing a function that processes network packets. At the moment I'm using a while loop so that the function is always running, but I would like to set a time in ms and at the end of that time the loop ends. Can you give me a tip? A snippet of my loop so far:

```py
    while True:
               
        status = pcap.loop(pd, 0, processing_pkts,
            ct.cast(ct.pointer(packet_count), ct.POINTER(ct.c_ubyte)))
        if status < 0:
            break
```

Thanks for any tips!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import time
end_time = time.time() + 60 * 10  //this will run for 600 seconds
while time.time() < end_time:
   // do your work
```